# Run Django project inside wordpress (on suburl of wordpress using Apache and mod_wsgi)

Tags: python, django, wordpress, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to run my wordpress site on main url like **www.example.com** and Django on its suburl like **www.example.com/djnago** using Apache and mod_wsgi.

I am trying to implement this on my local machine, I have created two separate .conf files inside /etc/apache/sites-available for both wordpress and django.

Separately, both are working fine e.g.,

at www.example.com -> wordpress is working

at www.abc123.com -> Django is working

But I want to run django at www.example.com/django from inside the wordpress project and its not working. What I have done is as follows :

**Hosts file :**

```
my_system_ip     wptesting.com/django
my_system_ip     wptesting.com
```

**files inside /etc/apache/sites-available :**

**for wordpress :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName wptesting.com
ServerAlias wptesting.com

DocumentRoot /path_to/wordpress

<Directory /path_to/wordpress/>
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny

allow from all
#            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#            Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**for Django :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /path_to/wsgi.py$

ServerName wptesting.com/django
ServerAlias wptesting.com/django

<Directory /path_to_project/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Error :** **www.wptesting.com** is working but **www.wptesting.com/django** is giving **404 not found error** and I think it first hits the wordpress project's url and then try to map the url **www.wptesting/django** from the urls defined in wordpress project which is why I am getting this 404 Not Found error. It means Django project is not getting hit at www.wptesting.com/django

Please let me know where I am going wrong, do I need to make only one .conf file inside sites-available and if so then what are the changes that I have to make or is there something else that is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"wptesting.com/django" is not a server name. "wptesting.com" is the server name, and you want to host the site at "/django" so that is the value you put for WSGIScriptAlias.

```
ServerName wptesting.com
WSGIScriptAlias /django /path_to/wsgi.py
```

Comment: exactly what I needed and its working . Please edit your answer and add few lines that It need only one conf file and I need to add above lines in wordpress conf file. Anyway Thanks a lot

Comment: one problem , Now the Url of django project are not working like I try to open admin -> www.wptesting.com/django/admin , It doesnot work but url becomes http://www.wptesting.comhttp%3a//wptesting.com/django/admin/ . Any idea why its happening