# How to host a Django project in a subpath?

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I am building an API with [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) which is served via Gunicorn and Nginx. The project "exampleproject" has to run at a subpath such as: https://100.100.100.100/exampleproject (example IP address). I do not have a domain name registered for the IP.

Currently, the start page renders as expected at https://100.100.100.100/exampleproject. However a the resource path for "products" does not work. Instead of https://100.100.100.100/exampleproject/products the start page displays https://100.100.100.100/products - which does not work.

I configured the subpath for `exampleproject` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` as follows:

```
server {

    # ...

    location /exampleproject/ {
        proxy_pass        http://localhost:8007/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

When I manually visit https://100.100.100.100/exampleproject/products Nginx records the following in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`:

> "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found [here](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#mounting-a-django-application-on-a-subpath) that one needs to add the following setting to Django's configuration in `settings.py`:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/exampleproject'
```

This seems to rewrite all paths for nested resources.

Comment: Document can find [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#force-script-name).

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the trailing slash from the proxy pass URL, like this:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8007;
```

If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, then keeping the `/exampleproject/` part.

See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Then you will need to configure Django to understand the URLs under `/exampleproject/`.

First, you can prepend the subpath to all URLs by updating the `urls.py` file like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [url(r'^exampleproject/', include(urlpatterns))]
```

And, in case you are serving statics and media just update in the settings:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/exampleproject/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/exampleproject/static/'
```

Of course you can create a custom setting to replicate this or to make the app work without a subpath as well, I believe this is a better solution than `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` because in that case I found we need to update the Django URLs anyways.