# How to properly serve a Django site under a Sub URI in Apache?

Tags: django, apache, mayanedms

I am trying to serve Mayan EDMS (a Django project) in a sub URI of another site. already checked and followed instructions from these posts:

1) https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/issues/350

2) [How to host a Django project in a subpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147916/how-to-host-a-django-project-in-a-subpath)

3) https://docs.webfaction.com/software/django/config.html#mounting-a-django-application-on-a-subpath

here is part of my apache config:

```
  # Mayan in running on http://0.0.0.0:8000

  ProxyPass /mayan http://127.0.0.1:8000
  <Directory "/mayan">
      Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
      SetHandler uwsgi-handler
  </Directory>

  Alias "/mayan-static" "/opt/mayan/mayan-edms/media/static/"
  <Location "/mayan-static">
      SetHandler None
      Require all granted
  </Location>
```

I added these in the Django settings file:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST  = True
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME     = '/mayan' 
BASE_PATH             = '/mayan'
STATIC_URL            = '/mayan-static/'
MEDIA_URL             = BASE_PATH + '/media/'
```

I expected that Mayan will be loaded in http://example.com/mayan,
but it redirects to http://example.com/#/mayan and returns a 404 error.

Did I miss something? or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this too in https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/-/issues/1002
and https://forum.mayan-edms.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5665.
Good news as apparently it is fixed in commit
https://gitlab.com/mayan-edms/mayan-edms/-/commit/2b567ed24a1e0c431a1d7cedca8e39923d47c5f4
Cheers