# URL for Static files in Django Project

Tags: python, django, apache, django-urls

I am running Django project at suburl like **www.example.com/django**  . Everything is working fine but my static files are not working on this suburl since they the url they are taking is main like **www.example.com/static/path_to_files** but it should take the url as **www.example.com/django/static/path_to_files**.

This can be the case for other urls too because I think whenever I use any url for any link it must take the hostname with the suburl like **www.example.com/django** instead of **www.example.com** .

you can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013379/run-django-project-inside-wordpress-on-suburl-of-wordpress-using-apache-and-mod) question of mine for more information about server configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` try:

```
STATIC_URL = '/django/static/'
```

More information here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yes it is working but for static files only . I need the same for all kind of urls .

Comment: Try adding `django` at the beginning of each `url` in `urlpatterns`

Answer (score 0):

You can serve them manually during development by adding the lines to urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Media files
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
        'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}
    ),

    # Static files
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
        'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}
    ),
)
```

Don't use this in production, and read the doc, its well explained.

Answer (score 0):

Define MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL in **settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = /django/media
STATIC_URL = /django/static
```

Then prepend this variable while defining url in templates:

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/path_to_media_file/">media</a>
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/path_to_static_file" />
```

Now you can use these variables wherever you want to create urls.